# How to change order by clicking Up and Down button in Asp.net core without using javascript

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there any way to click up/down button to change order of card in the UI.

i am new to programming and my english is not so well.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.languages)
            {
                <div class="card m-2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div>@item.DisplayName</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a asp-action="Up" class="btn btn-primary">Up</a>
                        <a asp-action="Down" class="btn btn-primary">Down</a>
                        <a asp-action="Options" class="btn btn-primary">Options</a>
                        <a asp-action="Remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

These cards are from Json

```
            var client = new WebClient();
            var jsonPath = (webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "/lib/LangData/languages.json");
            var json = client.DownloadString(jsonPath);
            var languages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Languages>(json);
```

Comment: You could use Blazor then or Java Script, I doubt there is any other good way to, else make a form that will change stuff and move it, then reload the page sure with new positioning.

Comment: Would you'd like to reorder the card from server side and then reload the page to render new ordered cards? If you can clarify more about the requirement and scenario, we can understand it better.